# fatal error call to undefined function curl_init() windows server2012RC

Tags: php

I am on a Windows SERVER 2012RC 64 bit OS, php 5.6.3

I've got an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

I removed the ; preceding the extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini. Restarted the Apache server but still getting the same error.

my `php.ini`

[my php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW2Uo.png)

[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFDGo.png)

Comment: did you tried viewing it in phpinfo() ?

Comment: yes,but just " cURL Sterling Hughes" here

Answer (score 4):

I fixed coping the following list files from php folder (in my case D:\xampp\php)
libeay32.dll
libssh2.dll
ssleay32.dll
to c:\xampp\apache\bin (or your apache\bin path), restart apache and works fine, apache's libraries were outdated

Comment: That solution is still actual (my env is: Windows 10, PHP 7.4.1, Apache 2.4.29 (Win64). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to php 7.1.6 on Apache 2.4 32bit version Windows 7 x64

this curl  implementation works:

1. C:/(path to php folder)/php.ini 
   enable extension=php_curl.dll

libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, libssh2.dll find directly in php7 folder

2. add this to Apache/conf/httpd.conf

   ## load curl and open ssl libraries

LoadFile "C:/(path to php folder)/libeay32.dll"
LoadFile "C:/(path to php folder)/ssleay32.dll"
LoadFile "C:/(path to php folder)/libssh2.dll"

Comment: For PHP 7.3 and Apache 2.4.x just copy the  libssh2.dll  module into the apache bin directory e.g. c:\apache\bin. The libeay32.dll doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7.3 and Apache 2.4.x just copy the libssh2.dll module into the apache bin directory e.g. c:\apache\bin. The libeay32.dll doesn't exist anymore.

And make sure extension=php_curl.dll is not commented out i.e

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```